# Having an issue with Route in Multiple User Dashboards in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have coded an application with four different types of users and my api queries are filtered only to render data based on the user access rights. Going to the frontend part as a beginner in react I thought it would be better to seperate my sidebars so as to avoid mistakes associated with users accessing a layout they are not supposed to see. Each and every Sidebar has got styles that control the display of data hence I had to declare the Routes in seperate files based of the Sidebar. The problem is that when I am trying to access the url links within these sidebars it gives me blank pages. Below is my code and I am apealing for someone to kindly explain to me where I am going wrong and where I should change as this is giving me too much of a headache.

```
 <div className={classNames(classes.container, !navDrawerOpen && classes.containerFull)}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/ts" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route  path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route  path="/form" component={Form} />
            <Route  path="/table/basic" component={BasicTable} />
            <Route  path="/table/data" component={DataTable} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
```

These are my routes in Sidebar or Teacher Dashboard

```
<div className={classNames(classes.container, !navDrawerOpen && classes.containerFull)}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/sm" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/smdashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/smform" component={Form} />
            <Route path="/smtable/basic" component={BasicTable} />
            <Route path="/smtable/data" component={DataTable} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
```

these are my routes in sidebar 2

```
const AppLayoutRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={matchProps => (
          <Component {...matchProps} />
      )}
    />
  );
};


export default (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <AppLayoutRoute exact path="/sm" component={StationManager} />
      <AppLayoutRoute exact path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

and in the lastfile I am trying to connect my routes to the router. As for AppLayout Route I had thought it would help me at least access those child routes and to be honest I was trying to implement solutions I read online and I am still failing to figure out on what I should do

Comment: I don't follow what you're attempting to do. I wouldnt seperate the routes like that but instead have one file with all routes and render the the links in the appropriate sidebar.

Comment: Thanks Mint let me try that and see if my theme can be controlled in both sidebars or what when using that approach

Comment: Why are you theming the routes? You should theme the respected page the route takes you to. You should put your code on codepen or something; you would get better help.

Comment: Thats a very good question I guess it has to do with me missing out on some concepts of this whole thing. Because first I used an admin template where I had links put on the sidebar and when I click the link it loads the page but the page completely loses the sidebar and I used the problem was linked to me declaring those routes on App.js. And for the last week I have been trying on this new approach and it has really messed my mind up bigtym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this [codepen](https://codepen.io/discountry/pen/RgNgGL).

Also, for you logic; when you get the user data I assume it includes the type of user (such as teacher, student, admin). You should add that data to your state. Then you use that to conditionally render the dashboard on the home page. So you could pass in something like `<Home type={state.user.type} />`

```
const { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } = ReactRouterDOM

const BasicExample = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link exact to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link exact to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home type={'teacher'} />} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

const Home = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>{props.type ? props.type: 'none'}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById('root'))

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you man for giving your time,,, you did open my eyes a lot

Comment: I returned my code as to how you instructed me and it takes me to my previous dilemna,,, I continue to lose my sidebar when I click a navigation link

Comment: do you have a repo? would help a lot to see the code.

Comment: Thank you Mint for helping me. My design was the one that poorly led me to that challenge. I had to create Layout which has got a header, sidebar, and navigation links wrapped in a sidebar drawer. Then the layout is used as a wrapper to child components. For Instance for students there is student Layout, teacher, there is a Teacher layout and the navigation links are seperated as per user types and that works well for me and serve my purpose for now. Thank you a lot for helping me